# Why does my google icon website keeps changing?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, favicon

I've installed chrome 3 weeks ago and fully changed from Firefox.

I started noticing one week in that my Google icon ([www.google.pt](http://www.google.pt)) website keeps changing to the League of Legends icon although I don't know why:

[image]

I saw today, this happens every time I restart chrome, I can't remember if it ever happened while running.
If I press Refresh, the icon goes back to normal, but if I search stuff, the icon keeps the same, which is quite annoying.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Have you tried smiting it?

Comment: If all else fails, you can always reset Chrome back to its [default settings](http://www.howtogeek.com/171924/how-to-reset-your-web-browser-to-its-default-settings/).

Comment: I don't know what theme did i installed, it was perhaps the most popular "black-flat" one... i reset it and it still happens...

Comment: Yea, i i'll try that, but this is kind of a fresh installation... 3 weeks old tops, anyway, i'll report in a few minutes.

Comment: Yea, the reset to default settings didn't work, only made myself more angry? lol, what are the other options? can't be from bookmarks, can't be from history, it reset'ed everything else...